# Stored Procedure with composite Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure like this :

```
select * 
from INVENTORYTABLE inv
join INVENTORYTABLE_New invNew on inv.Stock_ID = invNew.Stock_ID
where 
   (
   (AvailabilityStatus ='A' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'B' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'D' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'H' or AvailabilityStatus='E' ) And 
   MediaCount>0
   )
```

I want to sort the results by stockId for Availability status 'A' to 'H' and then for 'E'.
Is this possible?

What I want is to show results from A to H ordered by StockId and then E below the ordered by stock Id.

Comment: Why are you creating a `PROCEDURE` instead of a `FUNCTION` or `VIEW`?

Comment: `(AvailabilityStatus ='A' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'B' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'D' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'H' or AvailabilityStatus='E' )` would be easier written and clearer as `AvailabilityStatus IN ('A', 'B', 'D', 'H', 'E')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may implement an `ORDER BY` clause using a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN AvailabilityStatus = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
   stockId
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this will work.Greatly appreciated.

Comment: `CASE` is an expression that returns a value and it is not a control-of-flow operator,. In this situation, the `CASE` expression enhances the `ORDER BY` clause by allowing you to order results by a specific condition (`AvailabilityStatus` <> 'E' ).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from INVENTORYTABLE inv
join INVENTORYTABLE_New invNew on inv.Stock_ID = invNew.Stock_ID
where 
 (
   (AvailabilityStatus ='A' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'B' Or AvailabilityStatus = 'D'    Or AvailabilityStatus = 'H' or AvailabilityStatus='E' ) And 
  MediaCount>0
 )
order by 
 case
   when AvailabilityStatus ='A' then 1
   when AvailabilityStatus ='B' then 2
   when AvailabilityStatus ='D' then 3
   when AvailabilityStatus = 'H' then 4
   when AvailabilityStatus='E' then 5
   else 100
 end
```

You can try something like this